# Declare a member according to used constructor

Tags: c++

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int something) : m_something{ something } {}
    foo() {   }

    private:

        int m_something{};
};

struct bar
{
    bar(foo&  f)
        :
        m_foo{ f }
    {   }

    bar(int something)
        :
        m_default{ something } ,
        m_foo{ m_default }
    {

    }
private:
    foo m_default;
    foo& m_foo;
};
```

bar class can be constructed by reference of foo or it can initialize the foo itself. I want to get rid of  unnecessary initialization cost of   m_default  in case which bar  is constructed by reference of foo. I know it can be solved by using pointers but I want to stay within stack.

Is it possible ?

Ted Lyngmo's answer just worked flawlessly. I am sharing full code :

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo;
struct foo_own;

// only holds a reference
struct foo_ref {
    foo_ref(foo& fr) : m_foo(fr) {
        std::cout << "foo_ref constructor is called\n";
    }
    virtual ~foo_ref() = default;

    operator bool() { return false; }
    operator foo&() { return m_foo; }
    foo& operator*() { return m_foo; }

private:
    foo& m_foo;
};

struct foo
{
    foo(int something) : m_something{ something } {}
    foo() {   }

    private:

        int m_something{};
};

// owning a foo
struct foo_own : public foo_ref {
    foo_own(int something) : foo_ref(m_default), m_default(something) {
        std::cout << "foo_own constructor is called\n";
    }

private:
    foo m_default;
};

struct bar
{
    bar(const foo_ref&  f)
        :
        m_foo{ f }
    {   }

    bar(const foo_own& f)
        :
        m_foo{ f }
    {   }

private:
    const foo_ref& m_foo;
};


int main(int, char**) {
    foo foo_l;

    bar b{foo_l};
    bar b2{15};

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

> foo_ref constructor is called
>  foo_ref constructor is called
>  foo_own
>   constructor is called

Comment: Do you really need a reference member in `bar`?

Comment: what would that be good for? do you really need something to be a reference or a value?

Comment: @Mansoor no, that won't keep the temporary from being destroyed at the end of the constructor either way.

Comment: @Mansoor That still wont work.  const references only extend the lifetime of function local objects, not class members.

Comment: I am writing a tranmitter which sends bytes through an socket. Its use case is, it can simply use an socket by reference which is created somewhere else or it can create a socket in place by host address and port parameters. So corresponding types are bar => transmitter, foo => socket

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, I just simply forget to define it as const. It doesn't solve the problem but it simply must be const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could divide it into two types of `foo` wrappers:

```
// only holds a reference
struct foo_ref {
    foo_ref(foo& fr) : m_foo(fr) {}
    virtual ~foo_ref() = default;

    operator foo&() { return m_foo; }
    foo& operator*() { return m_foo; }

private:
    foo& m_foo;
};

// owning a foo
struct foo_own : public foo_ref {
    foo_own(int something) : foo_ref(m_default), m_default(something) {}

private:
    foo m_default;
};
```

To avoid future slicing and have a way of creating your `foo_ref`s and `foo_own`s that looks very similar, you could add a couple of helper functions:

```
auto make_foo_wrapper_ptr(foo& f) {
    return std::make_unique<foo_ref>(f);
}

auto make_foo_wrapper_ptr(int v) {
    return std::make_unique<foo_own>(v);
}
```

Comment: That's just what I need. The problem solved, i am sharing full source code in the question.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it!

Comment: I am again here, it is compiled but foo_own constructed ref doesn't live after it is constructed. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Not without context. If you do `foo_own apa(10);` then `apa` will live until it goes out of scope - and it can't live without its base `foo_ref`.

Comment: I now see that you have a `bar` with a `foo_ref&`. That reference will only be valid for as long as the object you used to initialize it lives. Consider making it a `std::unique_ptr<foo_ref>` instead - but still, if you've used a reference to initialize it, the owner of the data *must* outlive the `bar`.

Comment: Yea I am trying to solve that problem, but unfortunately could not achieved so far.

Comment: If scope is a problem, you may even have to consider dropping the whole reference idea. It's an unusual construction (although I've used it myself at times).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) that can either be empty (meaning hold an `std::monostate`) or hold a `foo`. `m_foo` should then be made to refer to the passed `foo&` in the first constructor, or the `foo` held by the variant in the second constructor.

In both cases, the rest of `bar`'s code should just use `m_foo` regardless of how the instance was constructed, since either way it refers to a valid `foo` object.

This requires C++17 support.

```
#include <variant>

struct bar
{
    // We do not initialize m_foo_var here so that it's going to be
    // default constructed as empty.
    bar(foo& f)
        : m_foo(f)
    {}

    bar(int something)
        : m_foo_var(something)
        , m_foo(std::get<foo>(m_foo_var))
    {}

private:
    std::variant<std::monostate, foo> m_foo_var;
    foo& m_foo;
};
```

Note that this gets rid of the initialization overhead, but not of the memory overhead. `m_foo_var` will still occupy `sizeof(foo)` bytes.